# How can I remap Capslock+h as backspace using AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

If possible, in Windwows I want to remap `Capslock+h` as backspace, as emacs keybinding, using `AutoHotkey`.

How can I achieve this? I have found following example https://github.com/catweazle9/emacs-everywhere , which does not have keybinding for `C-h`.

Comment: **AHK v1:** `Capslock & h::Send {BS}`  **AHK v2:** `Capslock & h::Send "{BS}"`

Comment: Should I just paste paste them into `ahk` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AHK v1:**

[Create an AHK script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Tutorial.htm#s12) and add this code to it:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

Capslock & h::Send {BS}
```

- Save the file and double-click the file to run it.
- Press Capslock+h to send backspace in the active window.

To get familiar with AutoHotkey  read the [Beginner Tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Tutorial.htm#s12).

**AHK v2:**

[Create an AHK script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Tutorial.htm#s12) and add this code to it:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

Capslock & h::Send "{BS}"
```

- Save the file and double-click the file to run it.
- Press Capslock+h to send backspace in the active window.

To get familiar with AutoHotkey  read the [Beginner Tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Tutorial.htm#s12).

**EDIT:**

To [this script](https://github.com/usuyama/emacs-like-key-bindings-windows) you can add

```
CapsLock & h::
  If is_target()
    Send %A_ThisHotkey%
  Else
    delete_backward_char()
  Return
```